# OOM issues with AllenNLP coreference resolution training and substituting models

Tags: pytorch, out-of-memory, bert-language-model, allennlp, coreference-resolution

I have a few questions about training and evaluating AllenNLP's coreference resolution model.

1. Are there any constraints/specifications on what GPUs should be used for training? I get an OOM issue midway through training on a Titan RTX GPU with 24220 MiB memory. Are there any parameters I can change that might help (note: I am using the [BERT](https://github.com/allenai/allennlp-models/blob/main/training_config/coref/coref_bert_lstm.jsonnet) instead of the SpanBERT version)?
2. I noticed that the [model usage examples](https://demo.allennlp.org/coreference-resolution) use an already trained and stored model. Can we instead specify a model path from a model we have trained?
3. Can we substitute `roberta-base` with `bert-base-uncased` in the [coref_bert-lstm.jsonnet](https://github.com/allenai/allennlp-models/blob/main/training_config/coref/coref_bert_lstm.jsonnet) file, or are other modifications necessary to make this change?

Answer (score 0):

1. This model needs a lot of memory. The `max_length` parameter makes the biggest difference to memory usage. If you can get away with a max length that's shorter than 512, try that first.
2. Yes, wherever it takes a URL to a trained model, you can substitute a local path to a model that you trained yourself.
3. Yes, you can, but you'll have to train the model from scratch.